# difference between int(a//x) and int(a/x) in python3

Tags: python-3.x, integer-division

Is there any difference between int(a//x) and int(a/x) in python3 if both a and x are integers.
Recently I got a wrong answer in a contest when I used int(a/x) but my code was accepted when I used int(a//x) .

Answer (score 1):

```
x, y = 3, 4
print(int(x/y))
print(x//y)
```

returns

```
0 
0
```

However:

```
x, y = -2, 4
print(int(x/y))
print(x//y)
```

returns

```
0 
-1
```

So yes. In case **one** of your input variables is negative an integer, the output of your variable differs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but in my case both x and y were integers. And I cast both (a/b) and (a//b) to int so they must have same type.

Answer (score 0):

`int(a/x)` cuts off the decimals (truncates the number). It doesn't actually do division in the `int`function.

`a//x` divides to floor (rounds down). It uses the BINARY_FLOOR_DIVIDE in bytecode.